# Mapping extension for MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mapping, extension

I am creating a wiki that allows people to specify the geographic range in which a species is found, something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Distribution_O._hannah.png). I would like to allow people to define these kinds of maps in some way, either by drawing or by specifying locations. Integration into a full-fledged mapping service, like Google Maps would be great, but I could live with something that only showed fairly coarse maps.

Is there a MediaWiki extension that allows me to do this, or am I stuck rolling my own?